# .click function not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have lots of jquery functions in my script but a particular one is not working, this is my function

```
  $('#delete').click(function() {
          var id = $(this).val();
          $.ajax({
                     type: 'post',
                     url: 'update.php',
                     data: 'action=delete&id=' + id ,
                     success: function(response) {
                             $('#response').fadeOut('500').empty().fadeIn('500').append(response);
                             $(this).parent('tr').slideUp('500').empty();
                           }
                 });        
         });
```

a similar function like this is working

```
<!-- WORKING FUNCTION -->
$('#UpdateAll').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'update.php',
            data: 'action=updateAll',

            success: function(response) {
                $('#response').fadeOut('500').empty().fadeIn('500').append(response);

                $('#table').slideUp('1000').load('data.php #table', function() {
                    $(this).hide().appendTo('#divContainer').slideDown('1000');
                });
            }
            });     
        });
```

I checked with firebug, the console doesnt show any errors, i checked html source the values are loading correct, i checked my php file 5times it is correct can't figure out the problem. Please Help.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? You do not see ajax call happens? The ajax request is sent but you do not see it appends?

Comment: nope the ajax request is not sent, even the function doesnt gets fired on click

Comment: upload your page and give us the url, will solve all the guesswork going on below!

Comment: Are you sure your page validate at [W3C](http://validator.w3.org/), have you got duplicate IDs or similar DOM issues? If it does why not upload the page, one of us will be able to diagnose the issues with the full source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of **id=delete** i changed it to **class=delete** in html and in js **('.delete')** and it is working fine now but when again tried with id it doesnt work.

Thank You all for Help, i dont have any problem whether it is id or class just the function works now.

Comment: Watch you remember about .delete, so it won't bite you down the track. It may be worth making the selector more specific, or the class 'delete-record'. Also, it'd be worth tracking down exactly why it doesn't work, in case it rears it's head again down the track.

Comment: I tried everything possible and i still dont know why it didnt worked with id=delete and worked with class=delete and i also tried renaming the ids to extremely unique names but nothing helped except class=delete

Comment: I was having the same problem and using class solved it for me too. But it was truly a class vs id problem for me. I was assigning a id to a div that was getting repeated multiple times. So duplicate id! BUT since I had this in a for loop of a mako template I overlooked the fact that it will be repeated multiple times, DOH!!! Lesson: Open the file in a browser and view the source, then see if the div element is repeated or not.

Answer (score 34):

I struggled with the EXACT SAME PROBLEM for 6hr straight! the solution was to use jquery 'live'.

And that is it.

```
$('#submit').live('click',function(){
...code...
});
```

Comment: when we use live function, jQuery starts keeping track of all the changes made in the DOM, that includes the new data/elements from the ajax request or removal of any element.

Comment: THanks a lot..I was stuck in the same problem for like 2 days..Just saw this post///live worked like a charm..:)

Comment: live is deprecated, `.on` should be used

Answer (score 5):

With the first one, I'd put a quick and nasty `alert()` within the click anonymous function, to ensure that it is being fired. Eliminate reasons why it may not be working. Also, try using Live HTTP headers or Firebug's console to see if the AJAX request is being sent.

If the click is not being fired, see if you have the selector correct. I often do this (quite nasty)

```
var testSelector = 'p:first ul li:last';

$(testSelector).css( { border: '1px solid red' } );
```

It won't always be visible, but if you see style="border: 1px solid red"` in the generated markup, you know your selector is on the ball.

Perhaps you have another click that is overwriting it? Try using

```
$('#delete').bind('click', function() {
  // do it
});
```

Comment: i added the alert but it is not getting fired but the alert is working fine with other functions.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem with a quick example I was working on. The solution was to put the click inside $(document).ready.  I was trying to use my element before it was actually ready to be used.

It's basic JavaScript to wait until the DOM is ready before you try to use an element, but... for whatever reason I forgot to do that, so maybe the same happened to you.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).on('click', '#selector', function(){
     // do something
});
```

jQuery 1.7+ has depreciated .live() and now uses .on() instead :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this applies in your context, but if you have parts of the page that are getting loaded by AJAX then you'll need to bind the click handlers after that content is loaded, meaning a $(document).ready isn't going to work. I've run into this problem a number of times, where certain events will fire fine until parts of the page are reloaded, then all the sudden the events seem to stop firing.

Answer (score 1):

Just use your `.click` with `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` because you are trying to apply the click event on a non-existent element.

Answer (score 0):

1) just before the last `});` you should add `return false`;

2) Are you sure that `#delete` exists? Also, are you sure is UNIQUE?

Comment: Yes the button exists <button id="delete" value="<?=$results[$k]['id'];?>">x</button> and it is unique id name.

Comment: I'd like to second the UNIQUE part. If the id, "delete" exists more than once in the DOM, you'll get unexpected results.

Comment: i tried placing a single button with same above code removing the html part with id of button=delete still it is not getting fired.

Comment: inspect the DOM with Firebug, can you see the element?  Does the value look kosher?

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but it's good to be aware of.
http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=1948

May not be an issue if you're not on Firefox 3.5.

Comment: The example page created by him is working fine without any errors.

Comment: Maybe take Firebug out of the equation. Even if the above bug doesn't apply, I've run into issues where Firebug has caused odd behavior in Firefox, at least temporarily. Restart Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

There is few things you can do:

1. like Elmo Gallen and Shooz Eh suggested, put your code in `$(document).ready(function(){...});`
2. code your `$('#delete').click(function(){...});` event handling AFTER your `<button>` tag,
3. use `$('#submit').live('click',function(){...});` like Parikshit Tiwari suggested.

Everyone of these should work ok.

EDIT: oops, didn't see that this was asked '09 :D

Answer (score 0):

I  think you must use `.on()` function for dynamically code run in jQuery like this:

```
$(document).on("click","#delete",function(){ });
```